# Truffle contract verify not working on BSC testnet

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, binance

I am trying to verify my deployed contract from truffle and getting "Etherscan has no support for network testnet with id 97" error. So I am working with Bscscan and I deployed my contract on bsc testnet.

How can I solve this problem?

My truffle-config.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const fs = require('fs');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();
const BSCSCANAPIKEY = fs.readFileSync("apikey").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard BSC port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    testnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545`),
      network_id: 97,
      confirmations: 1,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
    bsc: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org`),
      network_id: 56,
      confirmations: 10,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.12"
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    'truffle-plugin-verify'
  ],
  api_keys: {
    bscscan: BSCSCANAPIKEY
  },
}
```

Result:

```
> truffle run verify MyToken@{address}--network testnet
    Etherscan has no support for network testnet with id 97
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the latest version of `truffle-plugin-verify`.

Now the latest version is 0.5.4.

```
npm install truffle-plugin-verify@^0.5.4 -D
```

Why this happens?
In this file (https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify/blob/32ab0f698b1e151849ab463357cded664c5cffa3/constants.js)

You can see the last two API_URLs (56 & 97). This is added to the upper version rather than what you installed.

```
const API_URLS = {
  1: 'https://api.etherscan.io/api',
  3: 'https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api',
  4: 'https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api',
  5: 'https://api-goerli.etherscan.io/api',
  42: 'https://api-kovan.etherscan.io/api',
  56: 'https://api.bscscan.com/api',
  97: 'https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api'
}
```